# Function wrapper typing in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am rewriting an old browser extension in TypeScript, and came across a very hacky "convenience" function that's intended to wrap another function to effectively "hook in" to that function. While I am going to replace this function in the production code, I was curious if it's possible to write this in a way that satisfies TS, as my engine keeps putting up complaints.

Here's the (subjectively) best result I've gotten

```js
type GetReturnType<Type> = Type extends (...args: never[]) => infer Return ? Return : never;
type GetArgsType<Type> = Type extends (...args: infer Args) => any ? Args : never

export function wrapFunction<T, K extends keyof T>(
    parent: T,
    name: K,
    newFunction: (
        oldFn: T[K],
        ...args: GetArgsType<T[K]>
    ) => GetReturnType<T[K]>
) {
    var oldFunction = parent[name]
    parent[name] = (...args:GetArgsType<T[K]>) => {
        return newFunction(oldFunction, ...args)
    }
    return parent[name]
}
```

With this my engine emits the following complaint at the line starting `parent[name] = ...`

```
Type '(...args: GetArgsType<T[K]>) => GetReturnType<T[K]>' is not assignable to type 'T[K]'.
  'T[K]' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '(...args: GetArgsType<T[K]>) => GetReturnType<T[K]>'.
```

Comment: You want to avoid generic conditional types if you expect the compiler to understand what you're doing. Given your example I'd refactor to [this version](https://tsplay.dev/mLA0KW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That does fully address it, yes! If you could add an answer explaining that, I'd be very happy to accept it. Hopefully I can learn from your explanation too, I'm still pretty new to JS and TS in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is notoriously bad at reasoning about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  Your `GetReturnType` and `GetArgsType` utility types are implemented as conditional types (and, for what it's worth, similar to the [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and [`Parameters`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) utility types that are already available). And inside the `wrapFunction()` function, the types `T` and `K` are generic type parameters, so `GetReturnType<T[K]>` and `GetArgsType<T[K]>` are generic conditional types.  So we can expect the compiler to be unable to verify what values might be assignable to them.

Sometimes conditional generic types are the best way to achieve something and we have to just work around it, but other times you can refactor to avoid them entirely.  In your case, instead of starting with a function type `T[K]` and then teasing the arg list type and return type out of them, let's just start with the arg list type `A` and the return type `R`. We still need `K` for `name`.  Now we can rewrite all your types in terms of `A`, `R`, and `K`, as follows:

```
function wrapFunction<K extends PropertyKey, A extends any[], R>(
  parent: Record<K, (...a: A) => R>,
  name: K,
  newFunction: (
    oldFn: (...a: A) => R,
    ...args: A
  ) => R
): (...a: A) => R {
  var oldFunction = parent[name]
  parent[name] = (...args: A) => {
    return newFunction(oldFunction, ...args)
  }
  return parent[name]
}
```

The type `T` was originally meant to be "an object with a property whose key is of type `K` and whose value us of the function type we care about", so we can write that as `Record<K, (...a: A) => R>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) (a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), not a conditional type).

And you can see everything compiles with no error.  Now `parent[name]` is known to be of type `(...a: A) => R`, so there's no complaint when assigning the arrow function to it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOAxc15gA8A0ogKYAeUZYAJgM6IAKqcmZqUAnsWVwDSIAguSo0GidGC4BtALqCASgD4AFAChEiTOlQ0oALkSKyEOKlolBqgHR30RoQEpEAXmXHl-TYjDoAtmRGxN5aYGTIuJCwCEYaWlpwADa02GBxdjYOwi7uxqEJmboA5vSOPrkeiupOGfaOlcaIAN4+AG66iMmpeDFIrtq6+jJ+gXI+OnpgUCMBZHJuiLb2qKUNbh6tCYh6UCCoSOGRvQSq3VH4CIJFq-ROPgC+Prv7SJPDo-PqD0A)